# Why is there water dripping from my ceiling AC vents?

Tags: hvac, attic, air-conditioning

I have a one story house with hot water heat. The house also has forced air AC ducts running from the attached garage, in the attic, down into the living room, bedrooms, and kitchen. At certain times throughout the winter, water will drip from those vents. I **believe** it is from condensation forming in the ducts, and dripping down into the house.

If this is the reason, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condensation is probably the result of uninsulated ducts running through uninsulated cavities in your home.

The solution is to find out what section of your ducts this is occurring at and either swap the ducts with insulated ones or insulate that section of your home.

I recently learned this about my home.  I had uninsulated duct work in the uninsulated/not sealed crawlspace underneath my house.

Comment: Would just putting insulation around the ducts work? The ducts are running through my attic, which is not insulated.

Comment: @MJ01 It'll work.  Ideally you wrap the ducts, either in foam board (big supply trunks), foil wrap, or you can use normal batts.  You can bury them in loose fill too, but it's not quite as effective.